# I've written a matlab code for simpson 1/3 rule. I made a function for it and then i'm calling it in program

Tags: matlab

Here's the simpson function

```
%Simpsons 1/3 rule

function y = simpson(f,x1,x2,n)
global h
%global x1
%global x2
%h = (x2-x1)/n;
x(1) = x1;
sum = f(x1);
for i=2:n+1
    x(i)=x(i-1)+h;
    if mod(i,2)==0
        sum=sum+4*f(x(i));
    else
        sum=sum+2*f(x(i));
    end
end

sum = sum + f(x2);
int = sum*h/3;
disp(int);
end
```

here's the code in which i'm caliing:

```
CAo = 0.0625;
x1=0;
x2=0.8;
h=0.2;
n=(x2-x1)/h;
ep=2;
f=inline('(1+2*x)/((1-x)*0.0625)');
y = simpson(f,x1,x1,n);
disp(y)
```

On running the code, it's giving this error:

```
In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number
of elements in B and I must be the
same.

Error in simpson (line 12)
    x(i)=x(i-1)+h;

Error in tut_4_1 (line 8)
y = simpson(f,x1,x1,n);
```

i tried debugging, it showed my h is of 0 and my x(i-1) is 1X1. How to solve this. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the following line of code:

```
global h;
```

This deals with the scope of `h`.  The `global` keyword only affects the variable `h` during **the lifetime** of the function.  If you set `h` in the command window, then try to run Simpson's rule, the scope of `h` is different than what is seen in the function itself.  In fact, the variable `h` in file is **NOT** the same as what is seen in the command window.

You also have a mistake in your function.  You are returning `y`, but the output is stored in `int`.  You need to change this to `y`.

As such, there are two ways for you to fix this:

1. Place the actual code for calling Simpson's rule inside a function, and the Simpson's rule code as a nested function itself.  You would need to remove the call to `global h` and place it **outside** of the Simpson's rule code.  Something like this:

---

```
function [] = test_simpsons()

global h;

    function y = simpson(f,x1,x2,n)

    x(1) = x1;
    sum = f(x1);
    for i=2:n+1
        x(i)=x(i-1)+h;
        if mod(i,2)==0
            sum=sum+4*f(x(i));
        else
            sum=sum+2*f(x(i));
        end
    end

    sum = sum + f(x2);
    y = sum*h/3;
    end

CAo = 0.0625;
x1=0;
x2=0.8;
h=0.2;
n=(x2-x1)/h;
ep=2;
f=inline('(1+2*x)/((1-x)*0.0625)');
y = simpson(f,x1,x1,n);
disp(y);

end
```

You would then call `test_simpsons`.

2. This is the approach I recommend.  Simply make `h` an **input parameter** to your Simpson's rule code:

---

```
%Simpsons 1/3 rule

function y = simpson(f,x1,x2,n,h)
x(1) = x1;
sum = f(x1);
for i=2:n+1
    x(i)=x(i-1)+h;
    if mod(i,2)==0
        sum=sum+4*f(x(i));
    else
        sum=sum+2*f(x(i));
    end
end

sum = sum + f(x2);
y = sum*h/3;
end
```

---

The way you'd call your testing code is now:

```
CAo = 0.0625;
x1=0;
x2=0.8;
h=0.2;
n=(x2-x1)/h;
ep=2;
f=inline('(1+2*x)/((1-x)*0.0625)');
y = simpson(f,x1,x1,n,h);
disp(y)
```